# Extracting only portion of JSON document with REST API search call in MarkLogic

Tags: javascript, search, xquery, marklogic

I am looking out methods of Extracting only portion of JSON document with REST API search call in MarkLogic using JavaScript or XQuery.
I have tried using query options of re extract-document-data but was not successful. Tried checking my extract path using CTS.validextract path but that function was not recognised in Marklogic 9.0-1

Do I have to using specific search options like constraints or structured query.
Could you please help out? TIA.

I have below such sample document

```
{
"GenreType": {
    "Name": "GenreType",
    "LongName": "Genre Complex",
    "AttributeDataType": "String",
    "GenreType Instance Record": [
      {
        "Name": "GenreType Instance Record",
        "Action": "NoChange",
        "TitleGenre": [
          "Test1"
        ],
        "GenreL": [
         "Test1"
        ],
        "GenreSource": [
          "ABC"
        ],
        "GenreT": [
          "Test1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "GenreType Instance Record",
        "Action": "NoChange",
        "TitleGenre": [
          "Test2"
        ],
        "GenreL": [
          "Test2"
        ],
        "GenreSource": [
          "PQR"
        ],
        "GenreT": [
          "Test2"
        ]
      }
     ]

    }
}
```

in which i need to search a document with attribute "TitleGenre" WHERE GenreSource = “ABC” in the **GenreType** complex attribute. It's an array in json document.

I was using the search option as below, (writing search option in XML, but searching the in json documents)

```
  <extract-path>/GenreType/"GenreType Instance Record"[@GenreSource="ABC"]</extract-path>
```

I am still facing the issues. If possible could you please let me know how json documents can be searched for such specific requirement? @Wagner Michael

Comment: Could you edit your question to share the query options, particularly the extract-document-data part? And also the code snippet you used to validate the path?

Comment: Sure I add. I was traveling so code snippet was not handy.

Comment: cts.validExtractPath was introduced in MarkLogic 9.0-4. If you're on an older version of MarkLogic, cts.validIndexPath is the appropriate path checker.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract document data by using the `extract-document-data` [option](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44222).

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc := object-node {
"GenreType": object-node {
    "Name": "GenreType",
    "LongName": "Genre Complex",
    "AttributeDataType": "String",
    "GenreType-Instance-Record": array-node {
      object-node {
        "TitleGenre": array-node {
          "Test1"
        },
        "GenreSource": array-node {
          "ABC"
        }
      },
      object-node {
        "TitleGenre": array-node {
          "Test2"
        },
        "GenreSource": array-node {
          "PQR"
        }
      }}
    }
}   
return xdmp:document-insert("test.xml", $doc);

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search(
  "Genre Complex",
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <extract-document-data>
      <extract-path>/GenreType/GenreType-Instance-Record[GenreSource = "ABC"]</extract-path>
    </extract-document-data>
  </options>
)
```

In this case `/GenreType/GenreType-Instance-Record` is the xpath to the extracted element.
Relating to your comment, i also added a predicate `[GenreSource = "ABC"]`. This way only `GenreType-Instance-Record` which have a `GenreSource` of "ABC" are being extracted!

Result:

```
....
<search:extracted kind="array">[{"GenreType-Instance-Record":{"TitleGenre":["Test1"], "GenreSource":["ABC"]}}]
</search:extracted>
....
```

**Note**:

- You can add multiple `<search:extract-path>` elements!
- I had to change the name of `GenreType Instance Record` to `GenreType-Instance-Record`. I am not sure if you can have property names with whitespaces and access them with xpath. I couldn't get it working this way.

Please post your search options, if this does not work for you.

**Edit**: Added a predicate to the extract-path.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I m trying this. I will update here for sure.

Comment: How can i retrieve only the documents with filtered extract path in following example i need the documents with only "Source" = "ABC" ,so in extracted node it should return only those instances.{
            "Type": {
              "Name": "Type",
              "Type Instance : [
                {
                  "Id": "4022",
                  "Title": [
                    "AAA"
                  ],

                  "Source": [
                    "ABC"
                  ],
                  "Territory": [
                    "100"
                  ]
           } ]
}
}

Comment: How can i use extract-path with predicate / where clause condition such as    <extract-path>/Type[Source = "ABC"]</extract-path>, is there any way or solution to this kind of scenario? @Wagner Michael

Comment: Yes, this is possible! I edited my answer and added a predicate to my example!

Comment: Also note, not the full xquery grammar is supported in the `extract-path`. See following link for more information: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xpath#id_32278

Comment: Thank you Wagner.. I would try it and would let you know.. thanks for quick solution. :)

Comment: I have tried it but still not working for my specific example, could you please help me checking it for given json array sample document, on how to take the extract path and predicate for such requirement?

Comment: updated my answer. Had to change the property name of "GenreType Instance Record" to not have whitespaces. Could not get it working with whitespaces. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much Wagner, for your prompt trials. Helped me look out for accurate solution to my problem as of now. I have used below extract path, as i could not modify the names in documents. `/GenreType/array-node("GenreType Instance Record")/object-node()/TitleGenre[following-sibling::GenreSource="ABC"]`

Comment: Will this be good practice to use the way I have used? Any comments please?